# Number of outstanding shares from Financial Statement

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, financial-statements

I'm trying to self calculate P/E Ratio. From this I need to calculate EPS. For this I need number of shares outstanding.

Googling shares outstanding for Tesla in 2021 I see numbers like ~3.16 Billion.

How do I see this from looking at their Financial Statements? I don't want to rely on sites like ycharts etc...

https://tesla-cdn.thron.com/static/WIIG2L_TSLA_Q4_2021_Update_O7MYNE.pdf?xseo=&response-content-disposition=inline%3Bfilename%3D%22tsla-q4-and-fy-2021-update.pdf%22

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at a 2021 presentation that does not account for the 3:1 split that occurred in 2022. If you look at their most recent [10-Q](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000095017022019867/tsla-20220930.htm) (search for "outstanding"), they had about 3.15B in shares outstanding (not counting stock awards, warrants, etc.). If you look at their [10-Q from Q4 2021](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000095017022019867/tsla-20220930.htm) that is more closely related to the presentation you linked, they had about 1.03B shares outstanding, which is close to the 1.01B you can infer from the Net income and EPS (`2,321 / 2.29 = 1.01`)

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOO. Oh oh oh - totally haha nice spot mr D Stanley! Thanks